# SQL Server Unicode queries with SC Collation

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 I have a table with an nvarchar column with collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_**SC**, which is supposed to support unicode surrogate pair characters, or supplementary characters.

1. When I run this query:

   ```
   select KeyValue from terms where KeyValue = N'➰'
   ```

   *<strike>(above is a Unicode SC)</strike>*
   *above is a curly loop character with code 10160 (x27B0)* 
   The result is hundreds of different looking single character entries, even though they all have different UTF-16 codepoints.  Is this due to collation? Why isn't there an exact match?
   *EDIT: I now think this is due to collation. There seems to be a group of "undefined" characters in the UTF-16 range, more than 1733 characters, and they are treated as the same by this collation. Although, characters with codes above 65535 are treated as unique and those queries return exact matches.*
2. The two queries below have different results:

   ```
   select KeyValue from terms where KeyValue = N'π'
   ```

   returns 3 rows: π and ℼ and ᴨ

   ```
   select KeyValue from terms where KeyValue LIKE N'π'
   ```

   returns 2 rows: π and ℼ
   Why is this?
3. This is the weirdest of all.  This query:

   ```
   select KeyValue from terms where KeyValue like N'➰%'
   ```

   returns ALMOST ALL records in the table, which has many multiple character regular latin character set terms like "8w" or "apple".  90% of those not being returned are starting with "æ".  What is happening?

NOTE: Just to give this a bit of context, these are all Wikipedia article titles, not random strings.

Comment: Is the database collation SC-aware? It will affect string literals in your queries.

Comment: @RogerWolf Database's default collation is same, if that is what you mean.

Comment: How is `KeyValue`defined? `nvarchar(x)`, I assume ? or `varchar(x)`?

Comment: @SQLPolice Yes nvarchar(250)

Comment: How are you issuing the query?  By what kind of connection? Are you typing it into SMSS?  Or is it through a connection?  If the connection is not Unicode aware, it might be converting to ASCII, and so the first query becomes KeyValue=N'?'.  Which will match all single character entries regardless of collation.

Comment: @DavidDubois I'm using SMSS.  The thing is, as in the 2nd part example, the query using symbol for PI works (somewhat) as expected, so it must be fine for Unicode queries.

Comment: Here's an odd thing ... the character from your first query is CURLY LOOP  (U+27B0).  This character should not require a surrogate pair, and so the "SC" collation should be irrelevant.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidDubois Yes I think you are correct. I did not notice that. Now that first query returns 1733 results and the max of UNICODE(KeyValue) returned is 65532, for which UTF-16 should be sufficient.  I tried some queries with code values above 65535, and they return the exact match.  I will edit that and remove the SC specification, but why does the curly loop query not return the exact match?

Comment: I've reproduced your problem.  I created a table and populated it with rows with 1 character per row, using nchar(X), where X is every value from 1 through $1FFFF;    When I ran the query, it returned 5841 rows.  At first glance, I can't see any logic for which rows were returned.

Comment: @DavidDubois Can you try to group by that nchar column and order by the groups by size?  Do you see a large group at the top? The rest should be meaningful groups with a max size of 7 or 8.  I think this is due to collation.  I mention this in my edit.

Comment: It's certainly returning characters that are defined, among them space(0020), soft-hyphen (00AD) and Cyrillic character QA (051A)

Comment: @DavidDubois Yes soft-hyphen seems to be in that group for me as well.

Comment: Here's something interesting. I ran the following in both a database with SC collation, and one without.  Both times it returns "yes": How can space be equal to curly loop?   if nchar(32)= nchar(10160) print 'yes' else print 'no';

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server and thus tempdb also have their own collation, and they may not be the same as a database's or a column's collation. While character literals should be assigned the default collation of the column or database, the above (perhaps overly simplified) T-SQL examples could be misstating/not revealing the true problem. For example, an ORDER BY clause could have been omitted for the sake of simplicity. Are expected results returned when above statements explicitly use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx ('COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC')?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table with an nvarchar column with collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_**SC**, which is supposed to support Unicode surrogate pair characters, or supplementary characters.

The Supplementary Character-Aware (SCA) collations — those ending with `_SC` or with `_140_` in their names — do support supplementary characters. BUT, "support" only means that the built-in functions handle the surrogate pair as a single, supplementary code point instead a pair of surrogate code points. But support for sorting and comparison of supplementary characters actually started in SQL Server 2005 with the introduction of the version 90 collations.

> even though they all have different UTF-16 codepoints. Is this due to collation? Why isn't there an exact match?

1. UTF-16 doesn't have code points, it is an encoding that encodes all *Unicode* code points.
2. Yes, this behavior is due to collation.
3. There is no exact match because (as you guessed), code point U+27B0 has no defined sort weight. Hence it is completely ignored and equates to an empty string or any other code point that has no sort weight.

> There seems to be a group of "undefined" characters in the UTF-16 range, more than 1733 characters, and they are treated as the same by this collation.

Correct, though some only have a sort weight due to the accent sensitivity of the collation. You would get even more matches if you used `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC`. And, to be clear, the UTF-16 "range" is *all* 1,114,112 Unicode code points.

> The two queries below have different results ... Why is this?

I can't (yet!) explain why `=` vs `LIKE` returns different sets of matches, but there is 1 more character that equates to the 3 that you currently have:

```sql
SELECT KeyValue, CONVERT(VARBINARY(40), [KeyValue])
FROM (VALUES (N'π' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC), (N'ℼ'), (N'ᴨ'),
             (N'Π')) t([KeyValue])
WHERE KeyValue = N'π'; -- 4 rows

SELECT KeyValue, CONVERT(VARBINARY(40), [KeyValue])
FROM (VALUES (N'π' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC), (N'ℼ'), (N'ᴨ'),
             (N'Π')) t([KeyValue])
WHERE KeyValue LIKE N'π'; -- 3 rows
```

> This is the weirdest of all. This query: ... returns ALMOST ALL records in the table

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE NCHAR(0x27B0) = NCHAR(0x0000) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- 1

SELECT 2 WHERE NCHAR(0x27B0) = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- 2

SELECT 3 WHERE NCHAR(0x27B0) = NCHAR(0x27B0) + NCHAR(0x27B0) + NCHAR(0x27B0)
           COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- 3

SELECT 4 WHERE N'➰' = N'➰   ➰    ➰    ➰' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- 4

SELECT 5 WHERE N'➰' LIKE N'➰   ➰    ➰    ➰' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- NO ROWS RETURNED!!  (spaces matter here due to LIKE)

SELECT 6 WHERE N'➰' LIKE N'➰➰➰➰➰➰' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
-- 6
```

This, again, has something to do with the fact that "➰" has no sort weight defined. Of course, neither does `æ`, `Þ`, `ß`, `Ǉ`, etc.

I will update this answer once I figured out exactly what `LIKE` is doing differently than `=`.

For more info, please see:

- [How Many Bytes Per Character in SQL Server: a Completely Complete Guide](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/11/22/how-many-bytes-per-character-in-sql-server-a-completely-complete-guide/#utf16_support_and_sc_collations)
- [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)