# Adding a different string to a table fails

Tags: sql-server, types, sql-insert, constraintviolationexception

When creating a Table type with a single string column and trying to INSERT 2 differents strings make it fails.

First, I created a new Table Type with a single string column:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[String_Table] AS TABLE(
    [Value] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Value] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
```

Second, I try to add to a variable defined using this new table type 2 different string value:

```
DECLARE @p1 dbo.String_Table
INSERT INTO @p1 VALUES(N'')
INSERT INTO @p1 VALUES(N'')
```

On the second INSERT the following error is returned by SQL:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#A6AA779__07D9BBC3B1FF3702'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@p1'. The duplicate key value is ().
```

Please advise why this is happening because the strings are differents. The collation for the database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

*** NOT A DUPLICATE ***
In my opinion, my question is different from the other question because when you insert different strings you do not expect a primary key violation constraint exception. The underlying cause may be similar, but the way it occurs is different which would help someone else searching for this. My question provides additional insight to the collation issue and the reason why it occurs plus it provides a better understanding of why it occurs.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fecIedN1)

Comment: Try a *"supplementary character"* collation (`_SC`) like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`. See relatated (but not duplicate) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31214088/12597)

Comment: Background for other readers:  is U+1F4FA "Television Unicode Character"
and  is U+1F4A5 "Collision Symbol Unicode Character". Both encodings exceed 16 bits, so are encoded as UTF-16 surrogate pairs 0xD83D 0xDCFA and 0xD83D 0xDCA5. It appears that the default collation (if that is the proper term for nvarchar) treats these characters as equal.  `SELECT CASE WHEN N'x' = N'x' THEN 'Same' ELSE 'Different' END AS Compare` yields "Same". Adding `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC` to the comparison yields "different". (I am not a SMA, so I might not have the terminology exactly right.)

Comment: [Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SXSI1EZd) with @IanBoyd's suggested fix and two compare expressions.

Comment: The old fallback to `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` also works for performing raw binary comparisons, but `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` might also be preferable if code point sort order is desired. - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VZiazE2u).

Comment: @TN Not necessary, just needs to be a Windows Collation (ie not prefixed with SQL) and at least version 100 https://dbfiddle.uk/Qa5NGkZP so `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` is fine. And if using binary collation then version 100 should be used also